# sbt: run task on subproject

Tags: sbt

I have the following project structure:

```
lazy val root = project.aggregate(rest,backend)
lazy val rest = project
lazy val backend = project
```

When I execute the "run" task from the parent, I want a specific class from the "backend" project to have its `main` method executed.  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```scala
lazy val root = project
  .aggregate(rest, backend)
  .dependsOn(rest, backend) //<- don't forget dependsOn
lazy val rest =
  project
lazy val backend =
  project.settings(
    Compile / run / mainClass := Some("fully.qualified.path.to.MainClass")
  )

Compile / run := (backend / Compile / run).evaluated
```

Comment: Why is the `dependsOn` from root to `backend` important? The last line seems to work for me, also without it (i.e. `sbt clean` followed by `sbt run` does the right thing).

Comment: "<<=" operator was removed from sbt 1.x

Comment: Re: the removal of `<<=`, I've done by best to update the answer to use modern sbt 1 syntax.